# animate page from right to left or left to right?

Tags: xamarin.forms

in my application i am using PushModalAsync and PopModalAsync for page navigation but page animation is displaying from bottom top and top to bottom respectively. Is there any other option to animate page from right to left or left to right?

Comment: kindly help with normal and easy way to navigate to 2nd page with slide animation view from right to left or left to right

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage

Comment: but i never use any view and view model, i only create a simple app. so kindly help without MVVM type

Comment: You do not need MVVM for that

Comment: your project is not run in my pc , showing some error . so kindly suggest me which cs files are required for that animation.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

If using **PushModelAsync** , there is a workaround to achieve that effect .

Create a **[CustomPageRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view)** for PageTwo in **iOS** solution :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PageTwo), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace XamarinMoelNavigationStyle.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer :PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
            transition.Duration = 0.5f;
            transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionPush;
            transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromRight;
            View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);

            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }

    }
}
```

We will add animation inside `ViewWillAppear` method .

When poping to previous `MainPage` , we can deal with that in ContentPage as follow :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PageTwoView.TranslateTo(300, 0, 500);

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () =>
    {
        // Do something

        Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);

        return false; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
    });

}
```

Here `PageTwoView` is defined from Xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="PageTwoView"
             x:Class="XamarinMoelNavigationStyle.PageTwo">
     ...
</ContentPage>
```

Note : When `MainPage` navigate to `PageTwo` , need to disable the animation .

Such as :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageTwo(), false);
}
```

The effect :

[image]

===============================Update #1==============================

Also create a **CustomPageRenderer** for PageTwo in **Android** solution :

```
public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public CustomPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {

        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        Android.Views.Animations.Animation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(metrics.WidthPixels, 0, 0, 0);
        translateAnimation.Duration = 500;
        Animation = translateAnimation;
        translateAnimation.Start();

        base.OnAttachedToWindow();
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

===============================Update #2=================================

If there are much `ContentPage`s need to navigate, you can modify the `CustomPageRenderer` to be used for all ContentPage. As follow:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
...
```

Then using **[Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-preferences)** to set flag in Forms and get flag to know whether need the animation.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PageTwo pageTwo = new PageTwo();
    // set a flag here
    Preferences.Set("ModelAnimation", true);

    Navigation.PushModalAsync(pageTwo, false);
}
```

Now the renderer will know whehter need the animatin:

```
//Android
protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
{
    var myValue = Preferences.Get("ModelAnimation", false);
    if (myValue)
    {
        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        Android.Views.Animations.Animation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(metrics.WidthPixels, 0, 0, 0);
        translateAnimation.Duration = 500;
        Animation = translateAnimation;
        translateAnimation.Start();
    }

    base.OnAttachedToWindow();
}

//iOS
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    var myValue = Preferences.Get("ModelAnimation", false);
    if (myValue)
    {
        var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
        transition.Duration = 0.5f;
        transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionPush;
        transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromRight;
        View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);
    }
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
}
```

> after sliding complete 1st page is open as popup and not looking like first page to second page animation..

About this issue, you can share some code and `.gif` to explain that.

Comment: i need for both ios and android ...kindly sugest me for both

Comment: i want to use in every page so is to need create custom renderer for every page? is any solution for work in multi page from one renderer?

Comment: @KumarJit Okey, also can create a custom `PageRenderer` to achieve that. I have updated the answer. You can have a look at that.

Comment: you write a refference like [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PageTwo), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))] but when i used for multi page then which page name i used under typeof() in reference

Comment: PageTwoView.TranslateTo(300, 0, 500); this line will show error......TranslateTo property no exist

Comment: @KumarJit Do you define the `PageTwoView` in the `Xaml`? About `TranslateTo`, can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#translation).

Comment: now its working.....but when i navigate from first page to second its running ok but when i again navigate from second to third page its not sliding , because i refer only second page in custom renderer, so how to do multiple page. Should i have to create multiple renderer for multi page

Comment: And another issue is when i go to second page that animation is good but when i pressed back for go to first page slide working but after slide first page come as flash as popAsync. after sliding complete 1st page is open as popup and not looking like first page to second page animation..kindly suggest

Comment: @KumarJit You can modify renderer works for all `ContentPage` : `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]`. Then adding logic to control whether need the model animation when navigating.

Comment: @KumarJit I have updated the answer, you can have a look when you have time.My shared answer is a sample code, not sure be used other scenes. Maybe some scene need to add custom logic to fit your needs.